# r codes to model robust zero-inflated negative binomial and poisson

Tags: r

How to model the robust count data models such as zero-inflated negative binomial and Poisson in r, specifically I wanted their R codes if they differ from their standard normal but I believe they are

This is what I have tried

```
# Fit zero-inflated negative binomial model
zeroinf_nb_model <- zeroinfl(counts ~ predictor | 1, data = data, dist = "negbin", link = "logit")
```

but I believe this is more like the standard zero-inflated negative binomial not the robust zero-inflated negative binomial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for robust estimates of the *covariance matrix*?  If so, [this RPubs document](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/pscl) seems to give the answer, e.g.:

```r
library(pscl)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
fm_zip <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | 1, data = bioChemists)
coeftest(fm_zip, vcov = sandwich)
```

Using `dist="negbin"` seems to work just as well. To confirm that `vcov = sandwich` is actually doing something, run `coeftest()` without it and compare the results ...